# How can NGINX handle custom authentication URLs?

Tags: nginx

A lot of readings have led me down to people just suggesting OAuth modules for enabling authentication, however, OAuth is not a 1-size fits all solution and I have a custom authentication backend that validates tokens from a custom header.

Is it possible for NGinx to intercept requests, auto forward the header to the authentication service and only continue proxying IFF the response is a 200 and redirect to a login page otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html could be used for this purpose. I haven't used it myself, so I don't know how it works.

It looks like you configure the authentication endpoint as a reverse proxy target, and then you set the request headers with `proxy_set_header` directives.

This way you should be able to pass the needed headers to your authentication endpoint and get the authentication result back.